# why is my JFrame coming up blank?

Tags: java, jframe, graphics2d

my JFrame window keeps coming up blank. ive commented out everything else and just drew a square with my code and it showed so it must be my existing code thats wrong. please help.

please help me understand when i run my program why my JFrame window comes up blank

i am trying to make a graph of squares that would resemble an exponential function on a coordinate plane with lines connecting each square

here is my main method

```
/**
main method for running program
 */
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setTitle("Coordinate Plane");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        CoordinateComponent plane = new CoordinateComponent();

        frame.add(plane);


    }
}

/**
 * class for plotting coordinates
 */
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

public class CoordinateComponent extends JComponent
{
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        //loop variable
        int x = 0;
        //y coordinate variable
        int y = x*x;
        //previous coordinate variables
        //a = x and b = y
        int a = x;
        int b = y;
        //Graphics2D object
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        //rectangle object
        Rectangle square = new Rectangle(x, y, 3, 3);
        //line object
        Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(x, y, a, b);
        //x coordinate loop
        while (x <= 10)
        {
            if (x >= 1)
            {
                g2.draw(line);
            }
            a = x;
            y = x*x;
            b = y;
            x = x++;
            g2.draw(square);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `plane` before setting the `JFrame` visible. Also, you shouldn't draw on the EDT.

Comment: You're setting it visible before you add your plane

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Of course he should draw on the EDT. Actually, he should run the code from the main method on the EDT as well.

Comment: whats the EDT? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Comment: Post an [MCVE] (for example make plane a simple `JPanel`). It will not only help you get help, but most likely lead you to the solution.